# Dishwasher error e1 new world

Tags: electrical

My Newworld dishwasher error E1 display. On any program it will drain and fill with cold water but now it no longer sprays hot water after several minutes it drains again and fills with cold water.
Any advice would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

If the water is not hot after the DW has initially filled with water there may be too much cold water in the supply line. Try running the hot water from the sink until it feels hot. (The DW water supply is connected to the sinks Hot water lie).

If the water is still not hot enough (it should be heating to about 140F) it may be the heating element inside at the bottom. You'll need a voltage meter to check resistance of the element.

The E1 error code is (from my search) pump related. Specifically discharge of water cycle. As was stated in a previous answer check the drainage discharge flow. It should appear forceful until the cycle ends.

If not you will need to investigate further. Verify there are no obstructions in the DW drain hose. You can do this easily with a flashlight if th hose is opaque. Shine the light along the back of the hose and look for dark anomalies which indicate a solid mass.

If the hose is clear there may be a problem with the pump or the pump discharge port. This check involves removing the DW and disconnecting the service lines (power and water).

Once removed, flip it upside down to expose the pump. It is a round cylindrical-shaped container on the bottom of the motor attached to a large hose (the drain) and a narrower hose (the discharge hose). You should be able to disconnect both hoses and examine the inside for blockage.

Answer (score 0):

Your error code E1 is telling you there is a timeout on fill so shouldn't be related to not draining.
Take the drain hose from the waste socket and direct it into a bucket.
With a program selected, press start and close the door.
Watch how the water is being discharged by the pump.